# How to retain the application of multiple np.where() conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df, containing allocations for Stratification groups in a randomized controlled trial.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, "ABABBBAAAB"], [2, "BBABBBAAAA"], [3, "ABBAABABAB"]], columns=['StratID', 'Rand'])

df

    StratID Rand
0   1   ABABBBAAAB
1   2   BBABBBAAAA
2   3   ABBAABABAB
```

I want to use np.where to trim the length of the Stratification groups based on the StratID, so for example StratID 1 and 3 should be trimmed to only retain the first 6 allocations

```py
df["trimmed_col"] = np.where(df["StratID"].isin(
    {1, 3}), df.Rand.str[:6], "") 

df
    StratID Rand    trimmed_col
0   1   ABABBBAAAB  ABABBB
1   2   BBABBBAAAA  
2   3   ABBAABABAB  ABBAAB
```

But when I go to do this for the last remaining StratID 3 I overwrite what I've done above and get the following.

```py
df["trimmed_col"] = np.where(df["StratID"].isin(
    {2}), df.Rand.str[:4], "") 

df
    StratID Rand    trimmed_col
0   1   ABABBBAAAB  
1   2   BBABBBAAAA  BBAB
2   3   ABBAABABAB
```

How can I apply both changes to the dataframe at once so I get the following output

```
    StratID Rand    trimmed_col
0   1   ABABBBAAAB  ABABBB
1   2   BBABBBAAAA  BBAB
2   3   ABBAABABAB  ABBAAB
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for the help, but I'm hoping to keep the changes for both conditions. When I apply your code I get the original for either strata I haven't applied the np.where() on.

Comment: Now i see you put first result to "trimmed_col" column. So the command should be: `df["trimmed_col"] = np.where(df["StratID"].isin({2}), df.Rand.str[:4], df["trimmed_col"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to apply same conditions, I will go with np.select.

**Code**

```
conditions = [
    df["StratID"].isin({1, 3}),
    df["StratID"].isin({2}),
]
choices = [df.Rand.str[:6], df.Rand.str[:4]]
df['trimmed_col'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

**Input**

```
    StratID Rand
0   1   ABABBBAAAB
1   2   BBABBBAAAA
2   3   ABBAABABAB
```

**Output**

```
    StratID Rand    trimmed_col
0   1   ABABBBAAAB  ABABBB
1   2   BBABBBAAAA  BBAB
2   3   ABBAABABAB  ABBAAB
```

**Explanation**

If we need to apply single if else condition then it is good to go with np.where or df.where.
But, if we have multiple if-elif-else conditions then we can use np.select.

Here,
conditions list  - consists of all the conditions we want to apply.
choices list - consists of the choices/logic for the output.