# nesting numpy.where functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I  am adding a few simple data frames together consisting of 1 column and 10 rows. each element in the dataframe can be "1", "0" or "P"

```
criteria_1 = df['c1] + df['c2'] + df['c3] + df['c4']
criteria_1_mapped = criteria_1.map(lambda x: 'P' if 'P' in x else sum(map(int, list(x))))
df["criteria 1"] = np.where(criteria_1_mapped == 4, "Fail", "Pass")
print(df["criteria 1"])
```

This produce a dataframe that consists of pass or fail values. Exactly as i want. however there is a problem.  When a "P" appears in "criteria_1" sum i want it to appear in `df["criteria 1"]` as well.

i am trying to add in an additional numpy where statement to put a "p" in `df["criteria 1"]`  but i get an error. that says `"raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls}")"`

that error appears the i try to do this:

```
criteria_1 = df['c1] + df['c2'] + df['c3] + df['c4']
criteria_1_mapped = criteria_1.map(lambda x: 'P' if 'P' in x else sum(map(int, list(x))))
is_P_in_dataframe = (criteria_1_mapped == "P").any(axis=1)
df["criteria 1"] = np.where(is_P_in_dataframe, "P", np.where(criteria_1_mapped == 4, "Fail", "Pass"))
```

Any ideas how I can set df["criteria 1"]  to have "Pass", "Fail" and "P"

Comment: This might be a case for `np.select`. [Docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

Comment: Our problem is a candidate of np.select, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275218/how-to-retain-the-application-of-multiple-np-where-conditions/67275308#67275308
for np.select solution.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as follows:

```py
cond_list = [criteria_1_mapped.str.contains("P"), criteria_1_mapped == 4]
choice_list = ["P", "Fail"]
default = "Pass"

df["criteria_1"] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list, default=default)
```

`np.select` looks at the condition list from left to right and wherever it finds a match, it returns the corresponding value from the choice list. If no condition is satisifed, it returns the default value, i.e., `"Pass"` here.